# Configuring IntelliJ workspace views

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, configuration

Newb alert: moving from Eclipse to IntelliJ

I think what I want is "simple", but looking at menus, help and **doc** hasn't found it.  (I did visit their help and website links; I'm probably not looking for the right thing.)

For my main code editing experience, I like to have 3 main window panes:

1. Right side, large main area: source code editor
2. Left, upper part: project files in a browsable outline
3. Left, lower part: structural view of the current class I'm editing (method names, member fields, etc)

For IntelliJ, I can get the Project Structure on the left, OR the Structure of the individual class, but I'm having trouble getting the left half of the screen to show both the Project and Class hierarchy.

I've tried to dragging and dropping, like from Eclipse, but that doesn't seem to work the say it did in that other IDE.  (not arguing that it should, just something to try)

I think there are some general concepts that I might be missing.  And when I use IntelliJ help or Google for things "view", etc, I'm getting some other meaning of the word.

General questions:

- How do it (or CAN I?) generally arrange the IntelliJ IDE to look the
  way I like?  I'm happy to do some reading, but haven't seen this in
  the table of contents.
- Is it done by clicking and dragging?
- Or maybe it's that IntelliJ just uses different verbiage to describe these IDE elements, and if you now the correct language, then maybe Google
  promptly brings up the answer?

Any other Eclipse -> IntelliJ IDE config advice would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy to achieve. Instead of dragging the title bar of your panel, drag the button that opens the panel (see my screenshot). You can fully customize your view but dragging those buttons to either of the 4 panels (right, down, left up and left down).

[image]

Since you're asking for more advice on migrating, here's my approach to learn [IntelliJ shortcuts as an Eclipse user](https://eclectide.com/blog/2014/02/27/intellij-idea-shortcuts-for-eclipse-users/). It's my blog, so if it is seen as advertising, I will remove it.

Comment: Thanks!  You got me on the right track after a bit of experimenting.  For other newb readers, the position of the buttons on the left edge indicate where they will expand.  A button in the upper left edge will expand into the upper left window pane when clicked; a button in the lower left edge will expand into the lower left pane.  And to see both at once, expand both of them by clicking each button once, and they will share the left space. OK, now I "get it"!

Comment: BTW, since your blog is very much on topic, and you also provided an answer to my specific question here, I certainly wouldn't consider it "spam", and I will check out; I was hoping for resources like that.

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer is correct, please mark it as such ;)

Comment: Yup, had got distracted before, thanks for the reminder.